# Binding - dynamically choosing your data for a ListView column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here's the situation:  I have a list of objects, each referenced with an ID number.  I'm trying to set a value in a column of a listview based on the ID number of the object:

```
<ListView     Name="Listview1"
              Itemsource="{Binding ObjectList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header1"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subObject.property}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header2"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyOfAnItemInAList"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ObjectList is a property within the ViewModel, and proves an ObservableCollection to the ListView for processing.  Header1 and Header2 are bound to properties within the items found in the ObservableCollection called "ObjectList".

This all works fine for Header1.  The problem is Header2 needs to select one item from a list residing inside each element of the ObservableCollection, and display it based on another property of the referenced items in ObjectList.

So how do I do this?

I've managed to get it working by setting up a variable inside the objects in ObjectList called "currentSelection", which then gets set when the binding iterates through ObjectList from ItemSource to produce the ListView:

```
public ObservableCollection<theObject> ObjectList {

    get {
        foreach (theObject obj in sourceCollection) {

           obj.CurrentID = MyID;
        }

        return new ObservableCollection<theObject>sourceCollection // <-- secondary question:  Is this the best way to send an observableCollection to a View???
    }
}
```

However, this feels like a bit of a hack rather than a best practice, so is there another, better way to accomplish the same thing?

EDIT:

Here's a snippet of the objects inside ObjectList, as I have it now.

```
public class ObjectInObjectList {

    /* constructor and various properties snipped to save space */

    private subObject subObj;

    public int CurrentID {get; set;}

    public SubObject {

         get { return subObject; } // etc...
    }

    private SortedList<int,int> valuesIWantInSecondColumn

    Public int PropertyOfAnItemInAList {

         return valuesIWantInSecondColumn[currentID];
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you just looking for the best way to get MyID into the column with the header of Header1?

Comment: I reread it and now think you are trying to bind the "Header2" column to different properties depending on which Item is selected in another control and you accomplished this by using another property with a switch(CurrentID) statement that returns a specific property depending on the case. Is this accurate? Can you show the relevant code for theObject?

Comment: Lee - that's pretty much correct.  I'll add the relevant code in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the CurrentID property from the object. I don't want to have UI properties in my domain objects. I think the best solution is to use a multibinding for that column and give it the SortedList and your MyID value from the ViewModel, use a converter to return the selected item from the sortedlist. Something like this (assuming the listed combobox as well):

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Ids}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyID}" />
    <ListView Name="Listview1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subObject.property}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" >
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IDictionarySelector}">
                            <Binding Path="PropertyOfAnItemInAList" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.MyID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I tested this code and had to add the ToString() call to the return otherwise it was giving me a binding error that the textblock required a string value (thanks [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)):

```
public class IDictionarySelector : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length == 2)
        {
            IDictionary idictionary = values[0] as IDictionary;
            int? key = values[1] as int?;

            if ((idictionary != null) && (key != null) && (idictionary.Contains(key)))
            {
                return idictionary[key].ToString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. (+1)  I'll give this a try.  I'll also have a look at Sheridan's comment below and see if it's worth incorporating.  I think Sheridan makes a good point, too.  If it works out, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the properties in your `ObjectInObjectList` class. In particular, you need to tell the interface that the `PropertyOfAnItemInAList` property has changed when the `CurrentID` property has changed:

```
public int CurrentID
{
   get { return currentID; }
   set 
   {
       currentID = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentID");
       NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyOfAnItemInAList");
   }
}
```

This notification will update the `PropertyOfAnItemInAList` property in the UI each time the `CurrentID` property is changed, so you don't need any special kind of `Binding`.

Comment: I see what you're driving at with this, but it isn't what I'm looking for.  The objects that populate the ListView are within a list, and each one has a sub-list of elements that must be chosen based on a property of the parent element. ...

Comment: ... think of it like this:  Two sets of records in a clinic.  The first set of records is doctors, each of which performs a specialized service. The second set is patients.  Each doctor has multiple patients, and each patient can have multiple doctors.  Let's say that we want the listview to show a doctor's patients, and the number of times each patient has visited the doctor.  So, in this case, the list we have inside the object is the patient's ID number as an integer for the key, and the value is the number of times they've visited.

Comment: You're just making your life complicated like that. If you model your business rule using hierarchical data, it will greatly simplify your UI. By that I mean have a `Doctor` object and a `Patient` object... a `Doctor` would have an `ObservableCollection<Patient>` and a `Patient` would have an `ObservableCollection<Doctor>` among other things. Using WPF and MVVM, it's always easiest to provide *all* the data you need in the UI*.